# Why does container stop when closing VSCode window although "shutdownAction" is set to "none"?

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode 1.63.2 to ssh into a remote machine with Ubuntu 20.04, to then work on a project inside a Docker container. Whenever I close a VSCode window while executing a Python script in the container, it stops all terminal processes. When I reattach to the container, I see a Python terminal showing `Session contents restored from <date> at <time>` and the script's outputs up to the moment I deconnected from the container. However, I would like the container to just keep going when I close VSCode or shut down my local computer.

Things I tried so far: First, I cloned my GitHub repo in the remote machine and built a Docker image with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-bullseye
RUN pip install -U pip setuptools wheel &&\
    useradd -m -r fabioklr
WORKDIR /home/fabioklr/masterthesis
RUN chown -R fabioklr .
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
ARG GIT_HASH
ENV GIT_HASH=${GIT_HASH:-dev}
USER fabioklr
RUN git config --global init.defaultBranch main &&\
    git init &&\
    git remote add origin <url-to-remote-repo>
```

Then I ran `docker build .` for the image, `docker run -dit <image-name:tag> /bin/bash` to spin up the container, and I attached VSCode to the container with the `Remote-Containers: Attach to Running Container` command.

Second, I tried it without a custom Dockerfile and without the command line. I opened my project folder on the remote machine, chose the `Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container` command and a `Python 3` base image from the command palette. VSCode did the rest automatically, but still I encountered the same problem.

Third, I tried it with the same `Open Folder in Container command` but using the Dockerfile from above and a custom devcontainer.json file, where I specify `"shutdownAction: "none"` because it says in the [VSCode Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) that this setting should prevent my problem.

> Indicates whether VS Code and other devcontainer.json supporting tools should stop the containers when the related tool window is closed / shut down.
> Values are none, stopContainer (default for image or Dockerfile), and stopCompose (default for Docker Compose).

I managed to work around this issue with VSCode thanks to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396654/how-to-run-a-python-program-in-the-background-even-after-closing-the-terminal) by using `nohup`, but it is not ideal for my workflow. Plus, the problem is particularly strange because I did not encounter it a few weeks ago. Am I missing something or is this an issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Plus, the problem is particularly strange because I did not encounter
> it a few weeks ago.

Hi,
it sounds a bit like problem after upgrade.
Have you tried to downgrade *ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers* extension?
(right click -> install another version).

I am using *v0.245.2* and `"shutdownAction": "none"` keeps my container running when VS Code is closed.